# Windows tree command that follows .lnk links

Tags: cmd, directory, tree, treeview

so i have a folder structure that i want to make a tree of (im currently using the tree command), the current output looks like this:

```
C:.
└───example
    ├───example2
    └───folder with link
        │   link to example 2.lnk
        │
        └───other folder
```

would it be possible to show the destiny of the link?

example:

```
C:.
└───example
    ├───example2
    └───folder with link
        │   link to example 2.lnk -> example2
        │
        └───other folder
```

it doesn't have to look exactly like that, i just want to see the link destination

i tried to find something on the internet but the only thing i found, was a linux solution that looked like this

tree -l

```
.
├── aaa
│   └── bbb
│       └── ccc
└── slink -> /home/kaa/test/aaa/bbb
```

sadly -l or /l doesn't exist in windows